# CardAdded function not firing in UWP app

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I have an UWP app that performs a login either via username and password and via card reader.
That's my code.

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private SynchronizationContext uiContext = null;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        getMenu();

        uiContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        smartCard();
    }

    private async void smartCard()
    {
        string selector = SmartCardReader.GetDeviceSelector();
        DeviceInformationCollection devices =
            await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

        foreach (DeviceInformation device in devices)
        {
            SmartCardReader reader = await SmartCardReader.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
            reader.CardAdded += Reader_CardAdded;
        }
    }

    private void Reader_CardAdded(object sender, CardAddedEventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            SmartCardReader send = (SmartCardReader)sender;
            // some stuff
            Debug.WriteLine(send.DeviceId);
            // A card has been inserted into the sender SmartCardReader.
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("CardAdded Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Everytime my card reader reads a card, it only print the card code in the focused textbox, without executing the cardAdded function associated. I really need for the function to be triggered as soon as the card passed into the card reader.
Any suggestion of what I am doing wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

this line:
`SmartCardReader reader = await SmartCardReader.FromIdAsync(device.Id);` is the cupid. It create a local scope variable, and the event handler will be remove once leaving the local foreach scope. Move `SmartCardReader reader` to class scope will fix it for you.

Comment: I moved `SmartCardReader reader` outside the function. Right below `SynchronizationContext uiContext = null;` but nothing is changed

Comment: That's not correct.  The GC won't let that happen. -- Anyway, this code works fine on one device, and on another the event never fires. -- Seems to either be a bug in UWP card reader support, or perhaps there's another way to do it?